# How to use a symlog scale with log scale property of identical distance between labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis-labels

The plots below show 1st. a `symlog` scale (`ax.set_xscale("symlog")`) and 2nd. a `log` scale (`ax.set_xscale("log")`   As you can see the 0 does not appear in the `log`scale but my x values consist of `(0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100)`. I would like to find a way to have a scale like in the 2nd plot that shows my 0 value as well. A suggested solution is to use `symlog`. Plot 1 shows the result. 0 is there but the labels around 0 (0,0.001,0.01,0.1) are located  all right next to each other. I lost the property of a scale with identical distances between the labels no matter what value they have. Does anyone know how to fix that? 
[image: Symlog]

[image: Log]

Comment: To repeat my comment on the (now deleted) [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52554888/how-to-use-a-symlog-scale-with-log-scale-property-of-identical-distance-between), it is not clear what "identical distances" should mean on a log scale. Since `log(0)` is undefined, there is no metric that could possibly give you a "distance" between 0 and any other number on a log scale.

Comment: when you see my 2 plots you notice that in the first all values close to zero are ploted right next to each other while in the 2nd plot the "distance" between 0.001, 0.01 0.1 etc. is the same at the x axis

Comment: Sure, but there is no way to have the 0 at any (finite) distance on that axis. So the question really is, how would you like the plot to look like when using a log scale?

Comment: i get your point but I am sure there are ways to define the location of a label on the axis no matter the value. I am currently reading another post about `linthreshy`and hope this gives me the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: `ax.set_xscale('symlog',linthreshx=0.001)`did it while `0.001` is the smallest x value on the axis                                                               [image: symlog]